# How can I pass numeric vectors to generic vector functions?

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, parameters, casting, reference

I've noticed some strange behavior with vectors of type `int`, `uint`, and `Number`. Here's some code that you can test for yourself:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var untypeds:Vector.<*> = new <*>[{}, 7];
        private var objects:Vector.<Object> = new <Object>[{}, {}];
        private var sprites:Vector.<Sprite> = new <Sprite>[new Sprite(), new Sprite()];
        private var events:Vector.<Event> = new <Event>[new Event("1"), new Event("2")];
        private var booleans:Vector.<Boolean> = new <Boolean>[true, false];
        private var strings:Vector.<String> = new <String>["1", "2"];
        private var ints:Vector.<int> = new <int>[-5, -6];
        private var uints:Vector.<uint> = new <uint>[5, 6];
        private var numbers:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[2.5, 5.2];

        public function Main()
        {
            myFunc("untypeds");
            myFunc("objects");
            myFunc("sprites");
            myFunc("events");
            myFunc("booleans");
            myFunc("strings");
            myFunc("ints");
            myFunc("uints");
            myFunc("numbers");
        }
        // Note that I'm only using a string parameter for tracing purposes.
        // The same results would be seen if the vector was passed directly as an untyped argument.
        private function myFunc(vecName:String):void
        {
            var vec:Vector.<*> = this[vecName] as Vector.<*>;
            trace(vecName + " as Vector.<*>: " + vec + " Same object? " + (vec == this[vecName]));
            vec = Vector.<*>(this[vecName]);
            trace("Vector.<*>(" + vecName + "): " + vec + " Same object? " + (vec == this[vecName]));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
untypeds as Vector.<*>: [object Object],7 Same object? true
Vector.<*>(untypeds): [object Object],7 Same object? true
objects as Vector.<*>: [object Object],[object Object] Same object? true
Vector.<*>(objects): [object Object],[object Object] Same object? true
sprites as Vector.<*>: [object Sprite],[object Sprite] Same object? true
Vector.<*>(sprites): [object Sprite],[object Sprite] Same object? true
events as Vector.<*>: [Event type="1" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2],[Event type="2" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2] Same object? true
Vector.<*>(events): [Event type="1" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2],[Event type="2" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2] Same object? true
booleans as Vector.<*>: true,false Same object? true
Vector.<*>(booleans): true,false Same object? true
strings as Vector.<*>: 1,2 Same object? true
Vector.<*>(strings): 1,2 Same object? true
ints as Vector.<*>: null Same object? false
Vector.<*>(ints): -5,-6 Same object? false
uints as Vector.<*>: null Same object? false
Vector.<*>(uints): 5,6 Same object? false
numbers as Vector.<*>: null Same object? false
Vector.<*>(numbers): 2.5,5.2 Same object? false
```

Note that casting to Vector.<*> works fine in any case except for `int`, `uint`, and `Number`. In those cases, casting using the global `Vector()` function returns a copy of the vector, and casting using `as` returns `null`.

Is there any way to pass a numeric vector to a function that's meant to modify a vector of any type?

EDIT: I have just observed the same problem when trying to cast a `Vector.<int>` to `Vector.<Number>`, so having an extra version of the function for the three numeric types won't work.

Comment: _"when trying to cast a Vector.<int> to Vector.<Number>"_ that won't work. Vectors work on same data type only. In what way do you intend to modify the Vector array?

Comment: Pushing, splicing, and setting elements.

Comment: "Vectors work on same data type only." It appears that most vectors can be cast to `Vector.<*>` without issue.

Comment: Is there a pressing need to work with **Vector** at all? **Array** might be a little bit slower, but you will never know it unless you are processing a RALLY huge chunks of data that require a lot of processing power. Over almost 10 years of AS3 there was the only one time I actually had to resort to Vector.<int> because of performance issues: path-finding algorithms on large hexagonal fields.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Using arrays instead may be a workaround, but it's not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is there any way to pass a numeric vector to a function to modify a vector of any type?"*

Don't know if this is what you want but just use wildcard (`*`) as function's input parameter. This will allow you to use different numerical type Vectors.

```
var ints:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
var numbers:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();

ints.push( 5, 3, 7 );
numbers.push( -2.8, 1.5, -1.4 );

function vect_Push (input:*) : void
{
    input.push( input[input.length-1] * 2 );
}

function vect_Mixed (inputA:* , inputB:*) : void
{
     inputB[inputB.length-1] = inputA[inputA.length-1] * inputB[inputB.length-1];
}
```

In the above code...

- `function vect_Push` will take any `vector` or `array` (actually any datatype that responds to the `.push` method) and add one more new entry.
- `function vect_Mixed` will take two mixed `vector` arrays (so `inputA` could be `ints`, while `inputB` could be `numbers`. The last entry of one will be multiplied with respective other one).

To test the above code...

```
//#  test for : modify any vector (using Push to add one extra new entry)
trace("Old length ints     : " + ints.length); 
vect_Push(ints); //passing Integer to function
trace("New length ints     : " + ints.length); //should be +1 length
trace("Last new value ints : " + ints[ints.length-1]); //check new entry's value

//# test for : mixed vector types (multply types "int" with "Number")
vect_Mixed(ints, numbers); //passing Integer and Number to function
trace("New mult value numbers[last entry]  : " + numbers[numbers.length-1]);
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. I got as far as passing the vector to an untyped parameter, but I never thought to just leave it untyped instead of trying to cast it. This answer is perfect because now I can have functions that work on both vectors and arrays!